# What Facebook Privacy setting limit if the app of my friend can access my album?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am using the Graph API Explorer with permission "friends_photos" and able to access some of my friends' albums, but some are not.

e.g.

```
/johndoe?fields=albums
```

Since my friends are not aware of my app, so I guess they should have some settings applied so I cannot access their albums even I have the "friends_photos" permission used.

I am able to access their albums using the web interface. Where is the settings?

Comment: Aren't the result you get only paginated?

Comment: @IvanHanák, it return empty array

Comment: try another way: `johndoe/albums`

Comment: @IvanHanák, same, it return {
  "data": [
  ]
}

Comment: I get an empty array only if I miss the required permission `friends_photos`. I would advise you to simple remove your app from Account settings > Apps, and log in one more time.

Comment: The problem is: for some users, I can get the photos, but for some users, I get empty array, so it is not the problem os token...it should be related to the users' privacy settings.

Comment: Hi! Did you get any help from the answer?

Answer (score 9):

It should work perfectly unless a user has disallowed the apps to access a particular category of his/her personal information.

People on Facebook who can see your info can bring it with them when they use apps. However, a user can control the categories of information that people can bring with them when they use apps, games and websites.

You can find these settings under **Account Settings -> Apps -> Apps others use**. It will give a menu for choosing a particular type of information that apps can access. Something like:

[image]

As you can see, it's possible for a user to stop an app from accessing his/her photos. However, the photos will remain visible using the normal web interface.

Comment: That would have been my exact answer.

Comment: I would point out here that sometimes the Graph API returns empty array even if the permissions are granted (not just albums but photos as well), and in other times it might work with the same user. I couldn't find the reason behind this behaviour, but could reproduce it many times. If this is your case, the only solution I found is to make your app be aware of this problem and handle the case with a nice error message pointing to facebook as the sinner.