# Post in Facebook group feed has no "from" field

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, posts, facebook-group

I am playing with the Facebook [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to download the posts from a group that I'm a member of. Mostly this works fine, however some posts do not have a **`"from"`** field in the JSON output (but I can see them on facebook.com). Most of them do, but all posts by one particular user are missing this field. I assume this is a permission problem, but how do I know which permissions are preventing this field from appearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because the user has disallowed the apps to access a particular category of his/her personal information.

People on Facebook who can see your info can bring it with them when they use apps. However, a user can control the categories of information that people can bring with them when they use apps, games and websites. And, I think the user in this case has disallowed the apps to access his/her posts and that is why the `from` field in the JSON output is missing.

You can find more information about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866905/what-facebook-privacy-setting-limit-if-the-app-of-my-friend-can-access-my-album/20918602#20918602).