# FQL returning selected friend's checkin

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am writing a FQL query to read friend's checkins by passing their ID.

Select [Field1],[Field2]... From CheckIn Where Authod_ID =[Id Of Friend]

The issue is it returns checkIns for some of the friends , but returns empty for many.Although I can see their checkIn's in my facebook feed, so my account should have permission to view their checkIns.

Is there a special permission requirement for FQL to be able to read checkIns from my friends ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [FQL documentation for checkin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/), you need the `user_status` permission to read the user's checkins and the `friends_status` permission to read the user's friend's checkins.

> Although I can see their checkIn's in my facebook feed, so my account
>   should have permission to view their checkIns.

No. That's not always the case if you are using an APP to access the API. A user can disallow apps to access a particular category of his/her personal information. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866905/what-facebook-privacy-setting-limit-if-the-app-of-my-friend-can-access-my-album/20918602#20918602) for more information.

Comment: permissions should be ok as I can see many of my friend's checkin. It must their filter on whether apps can read their info.